# Argument in String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to log an error like this

```
logger.error("Entered value [" + val + "] is wrong")
```

But I don't want string concatenation because if you read the strings from right to left, they are in the wrong order. Is there any other way to do this?

I need to put `val` in the error message.

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: i need to put var inside string and provide value from outside.

Comment: Use logger.error(String.format("Entered value [%d] is wrong", val));

Comment: Which `logger` is that? And what value are you getting in the logs? What do you mean "not coming in correct order"? You mentioned RTL. Is there Hebrew or Arabic or another RTL text in `val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), like this

```
logger.error(String.format("Entered value[%s] is wrong", val));
```

This is supposing that `val` is a string. If it is not, you should change `%s` to something else (e.g., if `val` is an integer, you should use `%d`).

For further detail about format strings (like `%s`) check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: wouldn't this depend on his implementation of the logger? No information was given if he's using some library for logging or it's a custom logger

Comment: `%s` is able to manage any object, even primitives. `Object.toString()` will be used in those case. "_If the argument is null, then the result is "null". If the argument implements Formattable, then its formatTo method is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking the argument's toString() method._"

Comment: @AxelH if your comment is about my addendum on `%d` you would be right, but I like my format strings as I like my water: clear and without implicit conversions.

Comment: So do I ! But it can be well used with POJO based on the implementation of a `Formattable` or even in a generic context. But I prefer to use the correct "flag" when I know the type too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` function.

`String output = String.format("Entered value [%s] is wrong", val);
logger.error(output);`

Have a look at more examples in the following post https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples